# Dynamically generate GraphQL schema

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, express-graphql

One of my application requires Graphql schema that can have fields added & resolved on the fly based on the data. for example need something like

```
type Data {
   email: [String]!
   col1 :[Int]!
   col2: [Int]!
 ...col3:


}
```

where `col1 == nameOfColumnOne`, `col2=nameOfColumnTwo` etc will & be added based on the data and possibly set on the fly.

I am kind of stuck on this and will appreciate some help on this one please.

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just have a resolver `columns` that resolves a list of these columns that will grow over time? It makes more sense to me. I don't believe that you can achieve this modeling that you want.

you would have a `type Column` which defines what a column is supposed to be, and have:

```
type Data {
   email: [String]!
   columns: [Column]!
}
```

Hope it helps you :)